# Login to Facebook using older Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to build a custom tool for myself where I need a permission to read all user groups and be able to post to them.

I think that I can't achieve this using v2.6 API but in v2.3 all these features are still available. I know that it is deprecated, but if there is no way to do what I need in v2.6, for now it is ok to use v2.3.

I need to request a permission `user_groups` and post to `/{group-id}/feed`. I'm using Facebook SDK for iOS.

Is there any way to achieve this?

When I login requesting the `user_groups` permission, I'm recieveing the following error:

```
Invalid Scopes: user_groups. This message is only shown to developers. 
Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. 
Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
```

Comment: user_group doesn't not exists in any version anymore. Read the changelog

Comment: @WizKid I can see this permission in Graph API Explorer, and I can request it if user v2.3 or older.

Answer (score 0):

Generate your token using the depreciated v2.3 API and you will have access to the user_groups

[image: Facebook API v2.3]

Comment: I was able to use an old App Id, that allows me to use API v2.3. But I'm getting the following error in iOS when I request user_group permission on login.

Error Domain=... UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid Scopes: user_groups. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}